# Madrid-Segovia after 9pm on NYE

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, spain, madrid

Does anyone know any way I can get from Madrid to Segovia (Spain), leaving after 8:30 pm and arriving before midnight on 31 December?

I want public transport only (i.e. train/bus/coach but no shared car/taxi).

I have looked in Renfe (trains) and Avanza (inter-city buses) but the latest I could find was 8 pm on this specific day. Regular days do have much later services.

I appreciate this is quite a long shot but would be really grateful if someone could find me a way.

Answer (score 3):

That seems tricky. Last train leaves at 8pm and last bus at 7pm.

Other options to consider:

- Private car or Uber. Will cost you  around 120 Euro. Uber may charge a significant "prime time" surcharge for New Years Eve, so you would be better of booking a private car up front.
- Rental car for a one way seems too expensive, but may be an option of you are planning to return to Madrid anyway (as little as 30 Euro). Certainly not a good idea if you are planning to party in Madrid before departure.
- Private Ride share with BlaBla Car. Someone is offering the perfect times (21:30 depart, 22:40 arrive) for less than 5 Euro. Check out https://www.blablacar.co.uk/trip?source=CARPOOLING&id=2359292348-madrid-segovia

I'm not recommending or endorsing anything, but FYI: one of my sons lives in Europe and uses BlaBla Car frequently and is quite happy with it.